# write before read with Arduino Ethernet library

Tags: arduino, ethernet

A tcp server is implemented on the arduino using *EthernetServer(port)*, a connection is accepted using

```
client = server.available();
if (client) {
  ...
}
```

However, as far as I understand the source of *available* correctly, it returns a valid client only when there is something to read from this client object.

But I want to send a kind of greeting and a prompt as soon as the connection is established, so, before something has been sent to the connection from the remote side.

Who can I achieve that?

Comment: how do you known who to send to, with out a request? You need a client to make some kind of request before you can send them something. Think on a big scale, if your web server is available to the internet are you just going to push this message to every ip?

Comment: With a regular socket library like the BSD socket library you get the client from the accept call after the three-ways-handshake of TCP is complete. Try to open a connection to an SMTP server using 'nc mail.hottis.de 25' for instance. You will immediately see the greeting of the SMTP dialog without sending anything. And neither the nc application nor the TCP/IP stack sends any payload. Of course, packets are flying between server and client, but only the SYN and SYN-ACK of the already mentioned three-ways-handshake of TCP, no payload. And you can send as a server immediately after the accept.

Comment: ok sorry i missed understood the question. I was thinking in terms of a web server where a client would need to make a requests. I'm not sure it is possible to do what you want with the Ethernet library. you would probably have to make a custom library or override some of the methods